# Ruby on Rails Routes - difference between get and match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What would the difference be?

Example Match:
`match 'photos/show' => 'photos#show'`

Example Get:
`get 'photos/show'`

Wouldn't both make it possible to reach the photos/show URL and also use the show action in the photos controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 134, accepted):

`match` matches any http method/verb, while `get` matches only http method/verb GET.

Following two are equivalent:

```
match "/signup" => "users#new", :via => [:get]
get   "/signup" => "users#new"
```

Comment: If `via` wasn't specified what does match do then?

Comment: @userMod2 it will match any of the http methods, i.e. post, put, get, delete; all of them