# Custom url in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, url-routing

I know rails uses the controller action style urls like `www.myapp.com/home/index` for example

I would like to have a url like this on my rails app, `www.myapp.com/my_page_here` is this possible and if so how would I go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just use a `get` outside of any `resources` or `namespace` block in your `routes.rb` file:

```
get 'my_page_here ', :to => 'home#index'
```

Assuming you are using Rails 3+, do NOT use `match`. It can be dangerous, because if a page accepts data from a form, it should take POST requests. `match` would allow GET requests on an action with side-effects - which is NOT good.

Always use `get`, `put`, `post` or these variants where possible.

To get a path helper, try:

```
get 'my_page_here ', :to => 'home#index', :as => :my_page
```

That way, in your views, `my_page_path` will equal `http://{domain}/my_page_here`

Comment: Also add `:as => :my_page` at the end, and you get a `my_page_path` helper to use in your views.

Comment: A little late, but path helper generates path and not a url. So `my_page_path` will return `"/my_page_here"`.

Answer (score 4):

you just need to make a routing rule to match that url
in this case it will be something like

```
match 'my_page_here' => 'your_controller#your_action'
```

your controller and action will specify the behavior of that page

so you could do

```
match 'my_page_here' => 'home#index'
```

or

```
get 'my_page_here', :to => 'home#index'
```

as suggested in other responses.

for index action in home controller if you have such a controller

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more details

also see [Ruby on Rails Routes - difference between get and match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988866/ruby-on-rails-routes-difference-between-get-and-match)

Comment: `match` is old and should not be used!

Comment: you can use :via => [:get] to make the match respond only to GET requests. For normal static pages, match works fine. Rails is built in such a way that the app makers doesnt need to know the HTTP verbs - so for most content displaying pages rails offloads the burden of http using match.