# Custom URL in ruby on rails from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My question is related to [Custom url in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316048/custom-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

However, I want the user to be able to choose what their page name will be dynamically.  I don't want to hard code the page info in the route.rb file (get 'my_page_here ', :to => 'home#index') because my website allows users to create a unique page for their business and choose the URL.  For example:  www.mallstores.com/mycoolbusiness would actually go to www.mallstores.com/action/public/stores/12345

Is it possible to dynamically add/modify entries in the route.rb file whenever a user creates a new page from my website?

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to modify the route dynamically. You need to use [routes dynamic segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
so basically you should add the following line at the bottom of your `routes.rb`.

`get '/:store_name(.:format)', to: 'public/stores', as: 'public_stores'`

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
You must place this line at the bottom of you `routes.rb` so it wouldn't affect the other routes and it will be the last route to be tested.

Basically when a use navigate to http://yourdomain.name/store_name the `routes.rb` will send the request to the `public_controller` then to `stores` actions in the stores action you can grab the store_name from the url and look at it in your database then present it to the requester.

You can also utilize the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to enhance the process and to ensure the uniqueness of the store name.

---

**Another Technique**

You can place the following code in your `routes.rb` file

```
Store.all.each do |store|
  get "/#{store.name.parameterize}", to: 'public#store', store_id: store.id
end
```

- You must make sure that the stores names are unique.
- You should also place this at the bottom of your page to ensure that there will be no conflict.

but I prefer the first rule as it is more clean and what if you have like million store. then this would slow down the performance of your app.